# Count number of network cards to make if and else in a script

Tags: powershell, networking

I need to make different settings on the network cards.
Each one will have a different configuration, the problem I have is to identify, count and use in the script.

```
$InternalNet = Get-NetIPAddress | ?{$_.InterfaceAlias -match "Ethernet0" - and $_.AddressFamily -match "IPV4"}
$ExternalNet = Get-NetIPAddress | ?{$_.InterfaceAlias -match "Ethernet1" - and $_.AddressFamily -match "IPV4"}
$MaxInterNet = Get-NetIPAddress | ?{$_.InterfaceAlias -match "Ethernet3" - and $_.AddressFamily -match "IPV4"}
```

I will have machines with only 1 network card, machines with 2 network cards and machines with 3 network cards.
In the script I want to identify how many cards we have and to run one code or another depending on how many cards we have.

Comment: [Get-NetAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=win10-ps) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to get `$nics.Count` to return anything:

```
PS C:\temp> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Co...#3      10 Up           00-0C-29-37-DD-F2         1 Gbps



PS C:\temp> $nics = Get-NetAdapter

PS C:\temp> $nics.Count

PS C:\temp>
```

It looks like `Get-NetAdapter` returns a `CimInstance` object, not an array:

```
PS C:\temp> $nics.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                            
True     True     CimInstance                              System.Object
```

However, using `Measure-Object` we can access the `Count` property:

```
PS C:\temp> ($(Get-NetAdapter | Measure-Object)).Count
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-NetAdapter).count
```

Will return the number of network adapters available on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this

```
$nics = Get-NetAdapter

switch ($nics.Count) {
  3  { 
        <  your code for three adapters >
        break
     } 

  2  { 
        <  your code for two adapters >
        break
     } 

  1  { 
        <  your code for one adapters >
        break
     } 
  default {Throw "Error counting nics"}

}
```